# Android edge detection on open camera

Tags: android, android-camera, edge-detection

I've been looking into edge detection on Android and the examples I have found run the algorithm on a set image. I'm trying to use an edge detection algorithm to detect the edges on the camera app as you move the camera. I can't seem to find anything that allows me to pass in Bitmap values or any related objects to run the algorithm on without actually recording a video or taking a picture. Any idea on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting solution performing a realtime edge detection is this one.

https://github.com/arekolek/OnionCamera/tree/master/src/com/arekolek/onioncamera